# triggers of checkbox and dropdown list doesn't work simultaneously

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the explanation of the situation: When the value of a checkbox changes from true to false or vice versa, I have a VBA function that gets triggered and does a specific action based on the value. Now I want to add a drop down list to the same excel page, and another action must be performed dependent on the value of the dropdown list. To clarify, when the checkbox is checked, portion of the rows collapse, and when a yes/no option is selected from the dropdown list, the value in the following column is simply returned. Both triggers do not work for me at the same time. If one (checkboxes) is active, the dropdown is not. My code is as follows: especially the rows collapse doesn't work.

```
    Sub CheckBox1_Click()
            MutuallyExclusive "CheckBox1", "CheckBox2"
            HideSubProcedure "CheckBox1", "SubPro1.2", False, "SubPro1.2a"
        End Sub
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
        If Target.Column = 19 And Target.row = 17 Then
            If Target.Value = "Yes" Then
                Application.Range("AG10").Select
                Application.Selection = "This is a Google Restricted client - please contact your coach"
                Selection.Font.Color = vbRed
            ElseIf Target.Value = "No" Then
                Application.Range("AG10").Select
                Application.Selection = ""
            End If
        End If
        If Target.Column = 24 And Target.row = 248 Then
            If Target.Value = "Yes" Then
                Application.Range("A249:A256").Select
                Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            ElseIf Target.Value = "No" Then
                Application.Range("A249:A256").Select
                Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End If
        End If
Sub HideSubProcedure(CheckBoxName As String, SubrangeName As String, HideOnCheck As Boolean, Optional AlwaysHideBox As String = "false", Optional ClearContentsBox As String = "false")

    'Set initial parameters for error handling and identification
    On Error GoTo ErrorOccurred
    SetCurrentFunction "HideSubProcedure"
    Dim callingShapeName, activeSheetName As String
    callingShapeName = Application.Caller
    activeSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
        'Assign range of subprocedure to variable
            Dim Subrange As Range
            Set Subrange = ActiveSheet.Range(SubrangeName)
            'Subrange.Value
            
            If AlwaysHideBox <> "false" Then
                Dim AlwaysHideRange As Range
                Set AlwaysHideRange = ActiveSheet.Range(AlwaysHideBox)
            End If
            
        'Determine if subprocedure needs to be hidden or unhidden and assign to boolean
            Dim Hide As Boolean
            If ActiveSheet.Range(CheckBoxName).Value = True Then Hide = HideOnCheck Else Hide = Not HideOnCheck
            
        'loop through all shapes on the worksheet, if shapes is a checkbox that falls within the subprocedure range, then turn it off and hide/unhide it
            Dim sh As Shape
            For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
                If Not sh.Name = "CheckBox17" Then
            
                    If Not Intersect(Subrange, sh.TopLeftCell) Is Nothing Then
                        If sh.Type = 8 Then
                         If sh.FormControlType = xlCheckBox Then sh.ControlFormat.Value = xlOff
                        End If
                        If AlwaysHideBox <> "false" Then
                            If Not Intersect(AlwaysHideRange, sh.TopLeftCell) Is Nothing Then sh.Visible = msoFalse Else sh.Visible = Not Hide
                        Else: sh.Visible = Not Hide
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next sh
                                      
            'Optional: if an additional textbox was supplied, clear it.
                        
            If ClearContentsBox <> "false" Then
                If (ActiveSheet.Range(CheckBoxName).Value = False And ActiveSheet.Range(ClearContentsBox).Text <> "") Then
                Call pwcRemoveText
                        If PwCDeselectWarning.Tag = 1 Then
                            ActiveSheet.Range(ClearContentsBox).MergeArea.ClearContents
                            Unload PwCDeselectWarning
                        ElseIf PwCDeselectWarning.Tag = 0 Then
                            ActiveSheet.Range(CheckBoxName) = True
                            Unload PwCDeselectWarning
                            End
                        End If
                End If
            End If
            
            'hide/unhide rows of the subprocedure range
            Subrange.Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = Hide
            
            'Optional: if an additional info/commentbox was supplied and the subprocedure is unhidden, hide the additional box again.
            If AlwaysHideBox <> "false" Then
                ActiveSheet.Range(AlwaysHideBox).Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
            
            If ActiveSheet.Range(CheckBoxName).Value = Not HideOnCheck Then ResetAddInfo Subrange
        
            'release object
            Set Subrange = Nothing
            Set AlwaysHideRange = Nothing

    'Reset settings and exit sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
    
'Error Handler - call general error handling sub and pass error object and name of calling shape
ErrorOccurred:     ErrorHandler Err, callingShapeName, activeSheetName
End Sub
```

The checkbox_1 and the worksheet_change are triggers for the checkbox and dropdown respectively. Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "the same time"? They don't seem to be interacting with each other. Do you mean that the checkbox prevent the dropdown from working? Is it because you change the range of the dropdown? We have no idea what things like `HideSubProcedure` does. 
Do you want to run code on both events, or on the checkbox only?

Comment: I am afraid I cannot get you... Does "I have a VBA function that gets triggered" mean the check box `click` event which calls two other functions/subs you do not show their code? Now, what exactly do you mean by "Both triggers do not work for me at the same time"? When you say "drop down" are you referring to a Form Drop Down control? If so, did you assign a macro to be triggered when changed its value? Is it the sheet `Change` event to be triggered? Then,  no need to select anything to accomplish what the shown code tries doing... In order to receive any help, you must help us understanding.

Comment: @ChristoferWeber: Actually, the dropdown doesn't have to be a VBA procedure; excel data validation can suffice. There is no interaction or common ground between them. When I first tried the dropdown, it worked great, but when I clicked the checkbox, nothing happened. I want to use checkboxes and dropdowns based on the sheet's conditions. It's just a questionnaire that needs to be completed, with checkboxes and drop down menus as options.

Comment: @FaneDuru; Actually  the answer to your first question is yes. there is a vba code when the checkbox is clicked : basically it hides/unhide the rows.   when i referee to dropdown, it is simple excel data validation with yes/no options ( now no macro attached to it).

Comment: If "you want" doing something which (probably) happens in one of the subs/functions you do not show their code, how can we help? You still did not specifically explain what "Both triggers do not work for me at the same time" means. At least, on my taste...

Comment: "When I first tried the dropdown, it worked great, but when I clicked the checkbox, nothing happened. " Just to clarify, Did the checkbox not execute, or the dropdown after clicking the checkbox?

Comment: @FaneDuru the code is up dated

Comment: @ChristoferWeber:  what i meant is that when i start to work with the dropdown, they work perfect and then when i click the checkbox to collapse part of the sheet rows which are nor relevant, they don't respond at all.  and the same is true when i start with the checkboxes, they function well however, after clicking one checkbox and the next question is to be answered from the dropdown list. the drop down doesn't respond at all. in short: if i start with dropdown the checkboxes doesn't respond or if i started with checkboxes, the dropdown doesn't respond.

Comment: I still cannot get you... Do you want using the drop down before the check box event code and the calls sub finishes? What does "the next question is to be answered from the dropdown list" mean? Which part of your code points in this direction? What is `PwCDeselectWarning`? What `pwcRemoveText` does? Do you want the previous code to wait until you click the second control when its triggered code runs? I am afraid I cannot understand your way of asking... I feel I am wasting my time, no offence.